# dynamic add component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I want to dynamically add component in Container like Canvas(TileList constraints each child has the same size, GridList is poor in performance), for example

```
<mx:Canvas id="myHolder" width="600" height="550">

</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Button label="Add Button" click="addButton()"/>
```

when I click the button, I hope add a component(whatever the component is, and maybe each component has  different size), and if the total width of all added child is greater than `myHolder`, I hope the new child can begin in new line, and stretch the height of `myHolder` at the same time.(layout with custom code is better)

Comment: HBox doesn't work this way. It is horizontal box (as the name suggests) and packs children in one line. Thing that start new lines is called TileList (suitable for items of one kind). If your items are different, look into GridLayout or even lay them out with custom code on Canvas.

Comment: exactly, I want to display items have different size, Canvas is fine, but how to lay them out with custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Canvas you have complete freedom to lay components anywhere using their `x` and `y` properties, so there's a lot of ways to skin this cat. Since you need rows, one of the methods may be (not tested):

```
//inside of your Canvas-based component
private function updateChildrenPositions():void
{
     var rowY:Number = 0;
     var rowWidth:Number = 0;
     var rowHeight:Number = 0;
     for (var i:int = 0, total:int = numChildren; i < total; i++)
     {
         var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
         if (rowWidth + child.width > width)
         {
             //child will cause overflow, start next row
             rowY += rowHeight;
             rowWidth = 0;
             rowHeight = 0;
         }
         rowWidth += child.width;
         child.x = rowWidth;
         child.y = rowY;
         if (child.height > rowHeight) rowHeight = child.height; //accumulating max height
     }
     height = rowY + rowHeight;
}
```

This assumes Canvas has fixed width and set height depending on layout. You can add paddings and gaps later, it's a good exercise :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works well almost time.But sometimes the last child of each row will be truncated(set horizontalScrollPolicy="off")

Answer (score 1):

To get the functionality you want, I wouldn't use an `HBox`. As alxx suggested, a `TileList` would be a better fit in this situation.

Here are some examples using a `TileList` to get you started:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/halo/tilelist/

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/TileList

Comment: but each child of TileList has the same width and height, what if each child has different size

Comment: @jason, How much bigger or smaller are we talking? Is the size difference pretty large?

Comment: My component is composed by a label component and an icon component, but the text of label is different, some may very long, some may short, so how to handle it? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @jason, You can set your Label to be a specific width and have your text wrap around onto the line below. Just have the TileList's item renderer's height get set based on its contents. Check out http://blog.grio.com/2009/10/wrangling-flex-labels-autosizing-text.html for some more info on sizing Labels. :)